# AMP with Ruby on Rails : Impossible to use a a Google Font

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, amp-html, google-fonts

I am implementing AMP pages on my Rails app. However I can't get my font to work. It raises this error on the Google Search Console :

"CSS syntax error in the "amp-custom style" tag. Incorrect declaration."
Ligne 14:63 quot;Raleway", sans-serif}.banner{color:white;tex...

This is my application.amp.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="canonical" href="<%= url_for(format: :html, only_path: false) %>" >
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-youtube" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-youtube-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-font" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-font-0.1.js"></script>
    <% if Rails.application.assets && Rails.application.assets['amp/application'] %>
      <style amp-custom>
        <%= Rails.application.assets['amp/application'].to_s.html_safe %>
      </style>
    <% else %>
    <style amp-custom><%= File.read "#{Rails.root}/public#{stylesheet_path('amp/application', host: nil)}" %>
    </style>
    <% end %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <amp-font
      layout="nodisplay"
      timeout="3000"
      font-family="Raleway">
    </amp-font>
    <div class="amp">
      <%= render "shared/navbar" %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

And the beginning of my application.scss that I import for my AMP views which triggers the error on the Google Console :

```
body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

I tried everything, @font-face included, but nothing worked.

However, according to the official documentation (https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/custom_fonts) the link syntax should work with Google Fonts which is obviously a white-listed font provider allowed by AMP.

Comment: Please also provide the parsed html response which the browser gets.

Comment: where is the font? not seeing it address.

Comment: the error you've shared is not full / complete, can you please share the full error message and the css codes, (as the error is in your css code)

Comment: Take help from https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https://preview.amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-font
I am not able to debug it as it is in ruby n rails. If you can share any page without ruby n rails code, I can help you.

Comment: Please provide rendered HTML, the code above means nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things about the `@font-face` method.

1. The `@font-face` line has to be the **FIRST** line in your CSS stylesheet. Put all fonts imported this way at the top of the stylesheet.
2. It can be tricky linking to Google URLs, because Google gives a different URL for every browser when you get the actual font path. Raleway in Safari on my new MacBook gets the new **woff2** format:

`url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v13/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0IT4ttDfA.woff2') format('woff2');`

Use a different computer and Google serves up an older **woff** font: 
`url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v13/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ISQ.woff) format('woff');`

These will work, if your browser happens to be the one you were using when you got the font link, or equivalent. I couldn't get `@font-face` to work with the link in your HTML head: 
`href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600&display=swap"`. It seems to need a link to the actual font file, whether **.ttf** or **.woff** or **.woff2**.

The surest way is probably to download the font from Google, and use `@font-face` with the actual path to the font residing with the rest of your Rails application assets. Something like:

```
<style type = "text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: 'Raleway Regular';
src:url('/app_assets/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); 
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body {
font-family: 'Raleway Regular';
}
</style>
```

(I just put the style tags to demonstrate that nothing can go before the `@font-face` line in the stylesheet.)

To download, go to the [Raleway font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway) at Google Fonts. Select it with the red plus sign, then open the menu at the bottom of the page. Click the download arrow:

> [image]

The downloaded folder will contain 18 different style of Raleway, from Raleway-Regular.ttf to Raleway-BlackItalic.ttf to Raleway-Thin.ttf. You can use only the regular style like I did, or link them all in their own `@font-face` tags at the top of the CSS page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your font directly into your css file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap');
```

then you can create a class for this font or use it directly in body style:

```
.raleway {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; /* for set this font on every element you want by using this class
}
/* or in body style: */
body {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

Greetz Toxi